# Application/script for massive upload

Tags: 2013, web-services, file-upload, image-upload

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013.

Do you know if there is a client application or a script that works with web services to retrieve library list from a Sharepoint site and permit to upload documents/images from local hard drive directly on the selected library?

Answer (score 1):

There is client SharePoint tool that can upload a bulk of files to SharePoint document library using SharePoint Client Object Model.

The tool creates the same structure of folders / files in the SharePoint document library as source folder OR upload them directly into root of the document library. this use web service to upload the document to the SharePoint.

https://spuploader.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

does it matter how its done? if its not a requirement to do it that way than i highly recommend doing:

if not than use explorer view on the doc library. this way it opens a view like you would have on your desktop... from there you can drag drop, copy/cut and paste into that explorer window :)

if it is a requirement than you need to look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086(v=office.15).aspx

it uses Jquery and rest services(api) which i think is what your asking for.